# I have an error and for some reason the numbers are being changed and not the names?

Tags: javascript

This is the question that I need help on.

I need to have the names change randomly. I also need the names to be the same for both selection.

If you notice, it is possible to have the two random names be the same. I made some error and I need to fix this so that the first and second names are unique. I wanted to pass the first name generated to the `getoption` function of the second name so that second name cannot be this name. This is what i am having trouble with can someone please help me?

So far I have the code to make the numbers change but I'm not sure how to randomize the names

```js
 function getrandomnumber(min, max, notin) {
   return min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random())
 }

 function getoption(s, ch, num) {
   var a = s.split(ch);
   return a[num - 1];
 }

 var marymoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");
 var johnmoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");
 var maryitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");
 var johnitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");
 var marystuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));
 var johnstuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));
 var totalleft = marymoney + johnmoney - maryitem - johnitem;
 var str = "Mary had $" + marymoney + " and John had $" + johnmoney + ".          Mary buys a " + marystuff + " for $" + maryitem + " and John buys a " + +"            for $" + johnitem + ". They have $" + totalleft + ".";

 document.write(str);
```

Comment: It would help if you fixed your indentation. Please and thank you.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation for you

Comment: Make sure to follow the guidelines listed here http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to be a productive member of the community. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way!

Comment: The code works but the problem i am having is that the names are not changing randomly. I would appreciate some help please and thanks.

Comment: When you say names are you referring to the stationary items or the names of the people? If you're referring to the name of the people, that's hard coded in so you need to write code for that segment. If you're referring to the stationary items, try pressing the run button on my code to see that it actually does change randomly and is never the same between the two individuals.

Comment: I see. Are you simply wanting the two names to be switching places randomly or do you actually need different names as well?

Comment: Yes i need different names for instance every time i run the code i want different names of the people to show up

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to make sure the item names are not the same:

```
while(marystuff === johnstuff) {
  johnstuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));
}
```

You are also missing `johnstuff` from your `str` at the end.

Try running the code below to see that it works:

```js
var person1, person2;

function getPeople() {
  var people = ['Mary', 'John', 'Misa', 'Steve', 'Amy', 'David'];

  person1 = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
  person2 = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];

  while (person1 === person2) {
    person2 = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
  }
}
function getrandomnumber(min, max, notin) {
   return min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random());
 }

 function getoption(s, ch, num) {
   var a = s.split(ch);
   return a[num - 1];
 }

 var marymoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");
 var johnmoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");
 var maryitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");
 var johnitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");
 var marystuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));

 var johnstuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));

while(marystuff === johnstuff) {
  johnstuff = getoption("notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 7));
}
 getPeople();
 var totalleft = marymoney + johnmoney - maryitem - johnitem;
 var str = person1 + " had $" + marymoney + " and " + person2 + " had $" + johnmoney + ". " + person1 + " buys a " + marystuff + " for $" + maryitem + " and " + person2 + " buys a " + johnstuff + " for $" + johnitem + ". They have $" + totalleft + ".";

 document.write(str);
```

Comment: Hi i added the that part at the top that you have provided me with and it still gives me an error can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're also missing `johnstuff` in your `str` at the end.

Comment: Hi your code still doesn't generate new character names such as john

Comment: You're welcome. As you're somewhat new, be sure to follow the guidelines on how to respond to answers you receive to your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, that way you'll be a contributing part of the SO community.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```js
function getrandomnumber(min, max, notin) {
    return min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random())
}

function getoptions(s, ch) {
    var a = s.split(ch);
    a.sort( function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() } );

    return a;
}

var marymoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");
var johnmoney = getrandomnumber(50, 100, "");

var maryitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");
var johnitem = getrandomnumber(5, 20, "");

var stuff = "notebook,pencil,ruler,pen,eraser,binder,backpack";
var options = getoptions(stuff, ',');

var marystuff = options[0];
var johnstuff = options[1];

var totalleft = marymoney + johnmoney - maryitem - johnitem;

var str = "Mary had $" + marymoney + " and John had $" + johnmoney +
        ".          Mary buys a " + marystuff + " for $" + maryitem +
        " and John buys a " + johnstuff + "            for $" + johnitem +
        ". They have $" + totalleft + ".";

document.write(str);
```

Comment: Hi, when i run it both of the names generate Mary how do i make it so the names are not the same?

Comment: What is the full string that you get? I get something like this: "Mary had $51 and John had $62. Mary buys a backpack for $14 and John buys a ruler for $6. They have $93."

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, updated code, please recheck.

Comment: I want the code to generate random names and is the updated code above the comments?

Comment: Yes, new version does it, just run it.